# Are multiple UNIQUE (excl. PK and FK) constraints for one entity a bad smell?

Tags: database, unique-constraint

*My thought:*

A `Unique` field (not `PK`) is generally something which can be used to identify a entity as it's unique, event this concern is actually handled by the `PK`.

*Example scenario:*

I might use a `PK` 'id' with a number for identification use in my back end and db. I also might have a `Unique` field 'name' which is used for identification for a front end user.

This scenario makes it plausible to have a PK and ONE additional `Unique` field.

By using `Unique` this way, having multiple `Unique` fields for one entity, seems to me like a bad smell into the direction, that the db might not have been normalized.

Is this correct? Or what would be a plausible scenario to have multiple `Unique` fields (excluding `PK` and `FK`) within one entity?

Answer (score 0):

For example in an online shop you could make a user have an ID as primary key, his nickname used to identify him on comments he leaves and a shopping_basket_ID which connects him to a shopping basket where he can put things he wants to buy.

All 3 of those are unique and it's a plausible implementation.

Comment: But only the nickname will be a simple `UNIQUE` field. Id is a `PK` and the basket will be a `FK`. So there is actually only on simple  `Unique` field.

Comment: That is true. Unique fields are mostly alternatives to Primary Keys, they do not happen often since people mostly would rather put a UNIQUE field into a PK or just leave themselves more freedom in order to make the DB easier to use and do not even mark it as UNIQUE.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table of users as an example (and assuming a surrogate primary key to keep that out of the equation), you might want to enforce that all of these must be unique, since it probably doesn't make much sense to allow duplicates:

- user name
- email address
- SSN/NI number or equivalent
- combination of bank and account code
- probably more

Comment: This could be normalized by creating different entities IMHO. `Account` (username), `ContactDetail` (email), `Person` (SSN), `PaymentDetail` (account).

Comment: But wouldn't we then need to ensure that multiple users did not refer to the same `Account` or etc., by ensuring their FKs are themselves unique? Anyway, if we're just going to end up with a pile of tables with 1-to-1 relationships, I'm not sure that's worth the effort.